# jsPlumb best javascript MVC framework to associate with

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, ember.js, jsplumb

This is an opened question,

In order to make the best choice for my project, I need to know what is the best MVC javascript framework to couple with **jsPlumb 1.5.5 (jQuery)** to do the **easiest and the most robust implementation** in order to **handle all business logic and a clean code division**.

My choice will be made regarding these well-known frameworks :

1) **AngularJS**

This Stack post refers to a way to separate jsPlumb graphic code with AngularJS controller code (using a custom AngularJS service to handle jsPlumb logic) :
[Using AngularJS and jsPlumb (use jsPlumb functions in AngularJS controller)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573534/using-angularjs-and-jsplumb-use-jsplumb-functions-in-angularjs-controller)

And there is a simple implementation example here :
https://github.com/mrquincle/jsplumb-example

2) **Ember.js**

I found this Stack post, referring to an issue (solved) :
[Using jsPlumb in an Ember.js Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549494/using-jsplumb-in-an-ember-js-application)

3) **Backbone.js**

I only find one sample very very ligthweight..

I got some informations about these 3 frameworks thanks to this helpful link :

https://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/04/12/comparison-angular-backbone-can-ember/

I need to know what should be the best approach to make an heavy and clean front-end full-js application to achieve this kind of product :

http://equationmap.com/322/#.U1d8gfl_v-1

**From my point of view, AngularJS is the best choice today, but I want to understand if it's possible with this framework, to add some new HTML elements on the fly (jsPlumb elements creation) and to bind them an AngularJS business logic ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement, I would suggest you to try emberJS rather angularJS. Because([Source](http://eviltrout.com/2013/06/15/ember-vs-angular.html)):

> "Angular’s focus on simplicity has some serious consequences. There
>   are workarounds for some of these issues that you can implement
>   yourself in your project with great discipline, but ask yourself this:
>   are all developers on your team going to follow the same conventions?
>   Additionally, if you add all sorts of extra constructs to AngularJS to
>   make it work like Ember, why not just use Ember in the first place?"

Also take a look at: http://ryantablada.com/post/why-i-chose-ember-js

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your preference, familiarity with the framework and most importantly project requirements.

I started using `Angular` but ended up with `Backbone`.

IMHO Angular is ok, but the `learning curve is very steep`, sometimes very difficult to get the desired behavior, where as Backbone, I was able to come up with a TODO in 2 days and took more than 5 days to design a todo in Angular.

The only problem with Angular is it tries to `introduce it's own constructs`, where as Backbone is like plain javascript gives one all the flexibility. I haven't tried Ember but might surely work upon in near future.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but clearly my javascript knowledges are very low so the learning curve will be the same as Backbone.